# PHP: Creation of .tar archive extremely slow

Tags: php, linux, apache, tar

I want to pack around 10.000 files into a .tar archive using the code below. Nothing too big the size of the archive will not be more than a few 100MB. My problem is that this takes ages. Actually I am packing 9000 files for an hour now. On the shell this is done within 2 minutes, it is a powerful linux server running apache2. So what is wrong here? How can I increase the speed of the PHP script?

```
$Path = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($Path));

if (is_dir($Path) === true) {
  $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($Path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
  $archive = new \PharData('/var/www/test.tar');

     foreach ($files as $file) {                          
         $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
         $archive->addFile($filePath);
     }
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `PharData::buildFromIterator()`?

Comment: Run some simple profiling: add a timestamp after the `getRealPath` and `addFile` call.

Comment: If it's so quick from the command line, then why not call the command line from your PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecursiveIteratorIterator is quite slow... But question is why you use it? Try Phardata buildFromDirectory function:

```
<?php
...
if (is_dir($Path) === true) {
  $archive = new PharData('/var/www/test.tar');
  $archive->buildFromDirectory($Path);
}
...
?>
```

Hope is helps